# Which driver for USB enclosure should I install?

Tags: drivers, usb, hardware, hard-disk

I'd like to connect my old harddrive to my laptop via USB enclosure. I connected it but it only produced strange sounds, so I thought that the enclosure is corrupted.

I connected the enclosure to another computer and it's working.

The command **lsusb** shows:

> Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 IDE Adapter [GL811E]

So, I thought that it could be a problem with drivers (because on this computer more apps are installed).
Can I find out which driver is used on this computer for this particular device and how can I install it on my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

A easy way is to run `dmesg` to show the last kernel messages. Normally, the usb-storage driver is used to access generic usb storage device. So you usually do not need to install special drivers to access usb-harddisk.